# How to read the nested avro fields for creating streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have following AVRO message in Kafka topic.

```
{
"table": {
    "string": "Schema.xDEAL"
},
"op_type": {
    "string": "Insert"
},
"op_ts": {
    "string": "2018-03-16 09:03:25.000462"
},
"current_ts": {
    "string": "2018-03-16 10:03:37.778000"
},
"pos": {
    "string": "00000000000000010722"
},
"before": null,
"after": {
    "row": {
        "DEA_PID_DEAL": {
            "string": "AAAAAAAA"
        },
        "DEA_NME_DEAL": {
            "string": "MY OGG DEAL"
        },
        "DEA_NME_ALIAS_NAME": {
            "string": "MY OGG DEAL"
        },
        "DEA_NUM_DEAL_CNTL": {
            "string": "4swb6zs4"
        }           
    }
}
```

}

When I run the following query. It creates the stream with null values.

```
   CREATE STREAM tls_deal (DEA_PID_DEAL VARCHAR, DEA_NME_DEAL varchar, DEA_NME_ALIAS_NAME VARCHAR, DEA_NUM_DEAL_CNTL VARCHAR) WITH (kafka_topic='deal-ogg-topic',value_format='AVRO', key = 'DEA_PID_DEAL');
```

But when I change the AVRO message to following it works.

```
 {
"table": {
    "string": "Schema.xDEAL"
},
"op_type": {
    "string": "Insert"
},
"op_ts": {
    "string": "2018-03-16 09:03:25.000462"
},
"current_ts": {
    "string": "2018-03-16 10:03:37.778000"
},
"pos": {
    "string": "00000000000000010722"
},
"DEA_PID_DEAL": {
    "string": "AAAAAAAA"
},
"DEA_NME_DEAL": {
    "string": "MY OGG DEAL"
},
"DEA_NME_ALIAS_NAME": {
    "string": "MY OGG DEAL"
},
"DEA_NUM_DEAL_CNTL": {
    "string": "4swb6zs4"
}
```

}

Now If I run the above query the data will be populated.

My question is If I need to populate stream from nested field how can I handle this?

I am not able to find the solution in KSQL documentation page.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Out of curiousity, where's this message coming from? Depending on your source database, Debezium might be an alternative; as Robin is saying, we provide an SMT which lets you extract the "after" state of CDC messages.

Comment: Yes you are right but we are using OGG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robin states, this is not *currently* supported, (22 Mar 2018 / v0.5). However, it is a tracked feature request. You may want to up-vote or track this Github issue in the KSQL repo:

https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/638

Comment: Any idea when it is expected to be released.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It really helps. I appreciate that.

Comment: I can't give any specifics, but its high up on the list.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It helps in planning. :)

Answer (score 1):

KSQL does not currently (22 Mar 2018 / v0.5) support nested Avro. You can use Single Message Transform to flatten the data coming from Kafka Connect. For example, Debezium ships with `UnwrapFromEnvelope`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Robin It really helps. I appreciate that.